# running background services, ios & app rejection

Tags: ios, background-process, appstore-approval

I've read the chapter on the ios guidelines on background execution ( https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html )

From the docs, it is clear that passing the application approval process is not easy when your app needs to use background services. The app must have legitimate reasons for using such services, such as VOIP and geoTracking. Unfortunately, mine is neither of which.

My app plays an audio notif file ( plus vibrates the device ) at sun rise and sun set times. That's what the whole app is all about. ( I've got a formula that computes the daily sun rise/set times based on the users's current lat/log and timezone. )

Once it computes the daily times for that day, it simply sets up a timer and waits for that exact moment. And as date changes, it computes the formula again, so the new day's sun rise/set times adjusts transparently.

Since the sun rise and sun set times change on a daily basis, it is impossible to schedule a set time - like an alarm app would.

The easiest and most logical way to do this would be thru a timer. Because of this reason, I think this app's needs for a background service is very legit. But I really doubt that Apple will think the same way.

If the Apple rejects this, what strategy would I use (as an alternative way) to achieve the same goal? Any ideas? ( I don't want to use push notif ).

Comment: Why not use local notifications? You can calculate the sunrise and sunset times for the next 10 days (or whatever) and schedule a set of notifications.

Comment: Thank you. Local notifications won't play the  audio (which is set by user ) though. In my app, user has the choice of turning vibration on/off and choosing the audio file. With local notifications, It becomes an all or nothing deal. Plus, what will happen after 10 or xmany days? Also, when the user changes his location, the old set times no longer would be applicable. Sunrise/set times is a function of not just date and timezone, but also lat/long. It is because of these reasons, I had thought local notifications won't be a good alternative.

Comment: Have you figured out an approach?